# useBetween render count presented does not match render count calculated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

I have a simple react working example that shows *'App Renders: 2'*, yet the console logs only show the calculated render count getting to 1, but I'm not sure why.

Peering into the hooks through logs also doesn't ever clue me into when the render count gets to 2, and exactly why the render count is getting to 2.

link to working example on codesandbox, as well as code and console output follows:

[working example is also here](https://codesandbox.io/s/shared-form-with-use-between-forked-oi35n?file=/src/App.js:0-3220)

##### Code:

**- app.js -**

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { useBetween } from "use-between";

const useRenderCounts = () => {
  const [appRenderCnt, setAppRenderCnt] = useState(0);

  const bumpAppRenderCnt = () => {
    console.log(
      "bumpAppRenderCnt -> before setAppRenderCnt - appRenderCnt: ",
      appRenderCnt
    );
    setAppRenderCnt((prevRenderCnt) => {
      let newRenderCnt = prevRenderCnt + 1;
      console.log(
        "setAppRenderCnt old: ",
        prevRenderCnt,
        "new: ",
        newRenderCnt,
        "current appRenderCnt: ",
        appRenderCnt
      );
      return newRenderCnt;
    });
    console.log(
      "bumpAppRenderCnt -> after setAppRenderCnt - appRenderCnt: ",
      appRenderCnt
    );
  };

  return {
    appRenderCnt: appRenderCnt,
    bumpAppRenderCnt: bumpAppRenderCnt
  };
};

const useCounters = () => {
  const [sharedCnt, setSharedCnt] = useState(0);
  const incSharedCnt = useCallback(() => {
    setSharedCnt((sc) => sc + 1);
  }, []);
  const decSharedCnt = useCallback(() => {
    setSharedCnt((sc) => sc - 1);
  }, []);

  const [cnt1, setCnt1] = useState(0);
  const incCnt1 = useCallback(() => {
    setCnt1((c1) => c1 + 1);
    incSharedCnt();
  }, [incSharedCnt]);
  const decCnt1 = useCallback(() => {
    setCnt1((c1) => c1 - 1);
    decSharedCnt();
  }, [decSharedCnt]);

  const [cnt2, setCnt2] = useState(0);
  const incCnt2 = useCallback(() => {
    setCnt2((c2) => c2 + 1);
    incSharedCnt();
  }, [incSharedCnt]);
  const decCnt2 = useCallback(() => {
    setCnt2((c2) => c2 - 1);
    decSharedCnt();
  }, [decSharedCnt]);

  return {
    cnt1: cnt1,
    incCnt1: incCnt1,
    decCnt1: decCnt1,
    cnt2: cnt2,
    incCnt2: incCnt2,
    decCnt2: decCnt2,
    sharedCnt: sharedCnt
  };
};

const useSharedCounters = () => useBetween(useCounters);
const useSharedAppRenderCounters = () => useBetween(useRenderCounts);

const Renders = () => {
  const { appRenderCnt } = useSharedAppRenderCounters();
  return (
    <div>
      <p>App Renders: {appRenderCnt}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Counts = () => {
  const { cnt1, cnt2, sharedCnt } = useSharedCounters();
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Shared Count: {sharedCnt}</p>
      <p>Count 1: {cnt1}</p>
      <p>Count 2: {cnt2}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Buttons1 = () => {
  const { incCnt1, decCnt1 } = useSharedCounters();
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={incCnt1}>+ Count 1</button>
      <button onClick={decCnt1}>- Count 1</button>
    </>
  );
};

const Buttons2 = () => {
  const { incCnt2, decCnt2 } = useSharedCounters();
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={incCnt2}>+ Count 2</button>
      <button onClick={decCnt2}>- Count 2</button>
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const { appRenderCnt, bumpAppRenderCnt } = useSharedAppRenderCounters();
  console.log("App is rendering; before bump: ", appRenderCnt);

  bumpAppRenderCnt();

  console.log("App is rendering; after bump: ", appRenderCnt);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Renders />
        <Counts />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Buttons 1</h5>
        <Buttons1 />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h5>Buttons 2</h5>
        <Buttons2 />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**- index.js -**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

**console logs below:**

```
> App is rendering; before bump:  0
> bumpAppRenderCnt -> before setAppRenderCnt - appRenderCnt:  0
> setAppRenderCnt old:  0
> new:  1
> current appRenderCnt:  0
> bumpAppRenderCnt -> after setAppRenderCnt - appRenderCnt:  0
> App is rendering; after bump:  0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with the `<React.StrictMode>...</React.StrictMode>` tags. Or, more generally, that React is doing an additional render when in strict mode / development mode, from what I understand.

Removing these tags reduces the render count to 1, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

Recalling Render in StrictMode for React is a way to debug the new concurrent mode. This is also different for React 17 and 18. https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

To support StrictMode for React 18 use useBetween version 1.3.4

Greatly thanks!